# SQL Functions to turn inline

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I have a function inside a stored procedure that is making my sql go from 1 second to 10-14 seconds. Can someone help me merge them into a single inline function so that my sql is sped up greatly.

```
INSERT INTO
    #tempTable
SELECT DISTINCT
    PRODUCT.name,
    dbo.getProductTopImage(PRODUCT.name) as image
FROM
    dbo.PRODUCT
```

getProductTopImage Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getProductTopImage
(
    @PRODUCTNAME VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IMAGE AS VARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @ID AS INT

    SELECT TOP 1
        @IMAGE = PRODUCT.image,
        @ID = PRODUCT.id
    FROM
        PRODUCT
    WHERE
        PRODUCT.name = @PRODUCTNAME

    IF @IMAGE IS NULL   
        BEGIN
            SET @IMAGE = dbo.func_getImageRefs(@ID, 1)
        END

    RETURN @IMAGE
END
```

func_getImageRefs Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.func_getImageRefs
    (
        @ProductId AS INT,
        @Place AS INT
    )
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS

    BEGIN
    DECLARE @REF AS VARCHAR(20)
    SET @REF = '0'
        SELECT 
            @REF = PLANTIMAGE.imageRef
            FROM PRODUCT
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.PLANTIMAGE
        ON
            dbo.PRODUCT.hls = PLANTIMAGE.plantid
            WHERE PRODUCT.id = @ProductId AND PLANTIMAGE.imageNum = @Place

            RETURN @REF
    END
```

Comment: So when you replace `SELECT 
                    @IMAGE = PLANTIMAGE.imageRef` with `SET @IMAGE = dbo.func_getImageRefs(@ID, 1)` execution time increases ?

Comment: No sorry if I remove the "dbo.getProductTopImage(PRODUCT.name) as image"  from the stored procedure and replace with something like " '' as image" it goes down to 1 second to run. The above stored proc is only a snippet of a big query but it's deffo that function that's causing the slow down

Comment: It is still not clear where is the version that takes longer

Comment: Ahhhh I'm really sorry I hadn't realised that I'd moved the content of the 2nd function into my 1st. Have a look at the getProductTopImage Function again. So sorry about that

Comment: As it was pointed in the answer you are likely to be able to have this done with single a query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I don't think you need to use the functions at all.

```
with cte as (
    select *, 
        row_number() over (partition by name order by id) rn
    from product
)
select 
    c.name, 
    coalesce(c.image, pi.imageref)
from cte c
    left join plantimage pi on c.hls = pi.plantid and pi.imageNum = 1
where c.rn = 1
```

This creates a common table expression to store the `row_number()`.  Using that field, you can mirror your `SELECT TOP 1` statement.  Then you can use `COALESCE` and join to the plantimage table.  If the image from the `product` table is `null`, then it will return the image from the `plantimage` table if it exists.  You also need to move part of your `WHERE` criteria into the `JOIN` to maintain the `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: This looks mighty impressive I'll give it a quick go and see how we get on. Thank you so much for this suggestion.

Comment: this will default imageref to zero - `coalesce(c.image, pi.imageref, 0)`

Comment: also, if you can have several `plantimage` records with imageNumbe = 1 you will need to group by c.name

Comment: That's done the job. Thank you so much for helping me out tonight. That would have taken me an age to get too.